# Get localized country name from country code

Tags: flutter, dart, locale

Is there a Dart package or maybe a native method for getting the localized country name (String "Germany") from a country code (String "de") ?

In other languages like Java I've seen that it's implemented natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dart package flutter_localized_countries.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localized_countries